# In Swift, override func with parameters. Add Target to projects

Tags: swift

If I've a subclass, how is possible to deny the access at one func with other one with parameters?

Is easier to explain with code:

```
class A {
    func printSometing() {
        print("Class A printing")
    }
}

class B: A {
    override func printSometing() {
        print("Class B printing")
    }
}

class C: A {
    func printSometing(withPar:String) {
        print("Class C printing" + withPar)
    }
}

let prA = A()
prA.printSometing()

let prB = B()
prB.printSometing()

let prC = C()
prC.printSometing() //I don't won't that C can print this
prC.printSometing(withPar: " my free par")
```

the prints:

```
prA prints: Class A printing
prB prints: Class B printing
prC prints: Class A printing
prC prints: Class C printing my free par
```

Ok, is normal, but how I can avoid that prC can print "Class A printing"?

a work around is to write:

```
class C: A {
    func printSometing(withPar:String) {
        print("Class C printing" + withPar)
    }
    override func printSometing() {}
}
```

But I won't that who is using the func printSometing with class C, is forced to use only the fun printSometing(withPar:String) and not printSometing()

I'm sure that there is a solution.

**UPDATE:**

if there is no solution, I think that the only work around to force it is:

```
class C: A {
      var myPar:String
      init (withPar:String) {
          self.myPar = withPar
      }
      func printSometing(withPar:String) {
            print("Class C printing" + withPar)
      }
      override func printSometing() {
            printSometing(withPar: myPar)
      }
 }
```

let me know thanks

**UPDATE: MY REASONS**

Ok I'll explain. I've a game ongoing, in the project I've duplicate the target. So some file are in common in both targets, some other no. Example GameScene.swift is different. In the new target, I want make the same game but with small difference.
Example I've added a features at the player, but I wont preserve the original file. If I change the Player.swift in target 1, the same changes are in target 2. This because the Player2 class are 90% the same of Player. If I'll change some func in Player, Player2 change too.

> target 1: GameScene.swift
>
> target 1 and target 2: Player.swift
>
> target 2: Player2.swift

```
class Player: SKNode {
    //All my stuff
    func shot() {
        //bla bla bla
    }
}
class Player2: Player {
    override init() {
        //Different physics etc
    }
    func shot(withColor: SKColor) {
        //bla bla bla
    }    
    //All other func of Player.swift are available, ok I whant this.
}
```

Now what is the problem?
In may GameScene.swift of target 2, I can call shot(). But for the new game, is necessary to call only func shot(withColor: SKColor).
Ok I know this and is sufficent don't call shot(). But I'm thinking that tomorrow I forget this.

Another work around is to copy all Player.swift in target2. But if I'll add a func in Player.swift in target1, the func doesn't appear in target2.

Is the first time that I'm working with 2 targets in the project, I would be sure to do it correctly.
Thanks

Comment: No way to do it, it would break the liskov substitution principle

Comment: Thank you @dan , please check my update to understand if is the only way to proceed.

Comment: Your issue isn't that this *can't* be done, but that it *shouldn't*. It just doesn't make sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you all guys, I've added my reasons. @Alexander

Comment: Looking at your new code... Why not just make the function have a defaulted parameter?

Comment: @Alexander but the func shot() remain available..

Comment: Hmmm well then I would break down the various functionality of Player into several protocols, and make Player and Player2 conform to them. Then I would have to "Shootable" protocols, one that takes a colour and one that doesn't

Comment: @Alexander but Player2 doen't inheritance the protocol of Player?

Comment: Nope, they share all protocols but the one that defines shooting

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):

> *Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming stating that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e. an object of type T may be substituted with any object of a subtype S) without altering any of the desirable properties of T.*

This is called the *Liskov substitution principle* (as *@dan* pointed out in the comments) and the only way to not break it with what you want to achieve is through brute force, either with the code you provided in your question's edit, either with the following code (they are equivalent, without creating an unneeded variable):

```
class C: A {
    override func printSometing() {
        print("Class C printing")
    }
    func printSometing(withPar:String) {
        print("Class C printing" + withPar)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, but my problem is not this simple printing :) . I'm creating a new target from my app

Comment: @SimonePistecchia well, that is not really pleasant... Hope you will find a way to do that properly, maybe avoiding the `class`? Not sure what to say here, app targets aren't really my forte.

Comment: I've added an explain of target